# Capistrano or Ruby feature

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I was reading through [this](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/) article, because I am currently learning Capistrano.

I found this line on this page:

```
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name'
```

I am not sure if this is a Ruby feature or a Capistrano feature.

I checked Ruby for sets but it only has the datastructure Set(s).

I don't think this is a datastructure like set.

This looks like a key-value pair or a hash table where the value(s) right after the keyword `set` is the key and the string/value after the `,` is the value of the key-value pair/hash table (field).

Is this a Ruby feature or a Capistrano feature? What is the name of this particular feature?

Comment: Ruby doesn't require parentheses with most method calls. That's a call to the `set` method with a symbol (`:deploy_to`, sort of like an immutable string) as the first argument and a string as the second argument: `set(:deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name')`.

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks for the info. Sorry I am quite new to Ruby language. I will try this out to see your idea in action.

Comment: By the way, mu is too short, regarding the symbol ':deploy_to' where can we find references about this one? And what do you call this kind of variable? I have only seen this ':var_name' being used in attr_reader and attr_accessor. But will eventually be accessed with @var_name since they are instance/object variable.

Comment: `:deploy_to` isn't a variable, it is a Symbol literal just like `6` isn't a variable, it is an Integer literal. Check [the Symbol docs](http://ruby-doc.com/core/classes/Symbol.html) and maybe do some googling for "ruby symbol".

Comment: Ah ok. This is something I have yet to know in Ruby. Thank you so much @muistooshort. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's `set(:deploy_to, '/var/www/my_app_name')` with omitted parentheses. Capistrano's [`set`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/9fbb73b5f53d45b233b0c8f9ee5482cb7ef5e9c9/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb#L37-L43) method has nothing to do with sets (collections). It's used to _set_ a variable (here: `deploy_to` to `'/var/www/my_app_name'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Ruby feature. It is called a "*message send*". If you are familiar with other languages, they call it a "subroutine call", "method call", "function call", "function application", "procedure call", or similar.

More precisely, it is a receiverless message send to the implicit receiver `self` with two arguments, the first being the symbol literal `:deploy_to`, the second being the string literal `'/var/www/my_app_name'`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. My apologies, I am quite new to Ruby language but yes I am familiar with other languages. I was just expecting there was parentheses there. I will try this out myself to see your answer in action.